# How can I write the unit Einstein in LaTeX (siunitx)?

Tags: siunitx, units

I am currently writing my master's thesis with LaTeX and most things really go super good and a lot better than in Word, but I can't seem to get this one working. What I want:

```
60 yE/m2s (I hope you know what I mean...)
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
\SI{60}{\micro\einstein\per\meter\squared\second}
```

I installed the package correctly as it's working fine with other units like:

```
\SI{20}{\degreeCelsius}
```

Comment: Einstein is no SI unit

Comment: Isn't y = yokto? Or did you mean to write µ?

Answer (score 19):

Einstein is not among the units available by default in `siunitx`, but you can declare a new unit.

Note also that you need `\per` for each unit in the denominator unless you've set `sticky-per=true`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\einstein}{E}
\begin{document}

\SI{60}{\micro\einstein\per\meter\squared\per\second}

\sisetup{sticky-per=true} %add to preamble for global setting

\SI{60}{\micro\einstein\per\meter\squared\second}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need one `\per` per unit if you use the `sticky-per` option